# Mean field theory of an Ising antiferromagnet

Tags: electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics, ising-model, spin-models, mean-field-theory

I am calculating the free energy of an Ising antiferromagnet under the static magnetic field, and trying to get an expansion of free energy near the Neel temperature.
But my calculation leads to a somewhat odd behavior about the sign of $m^2$.

The model is as follows:
hamiltonian $$\mathscr{H} = J \sum _{<i,j>}\sigma _i ^A \sigma _j^B - h(\sum_{i}^{N/2}\sigma_i^A + \sum_{j}^{N/2}\sigma_j^B),$$
where $J>0, ~\sigma=\pm1$.

Using $\sigma_i^A=<\sigma_i^A> + (\sigma_i^A-<\sigma_i^A>)$,
and $\sigma_j^B=<\sigma_j^B> + (\sigma_j^B-<\sigma_j^B>)$, the mean field hamiltonian becomes
$$\mathscr{H}_{MF}=-\frac{1}{2}zJNm_Am_B + (zJm_A-h)\sum_{j}^{N/2}\sigma_j^B + (zJm_B-h)\sum_{i}^{N/2}\sigma_i^A.$$

Then, the partition function becomes
$$Z_{MF} = e^{\beta zJNm_A m_B/2}[2\cosh\{-\beta(zJm_A-h)\}]^{N/2} \cdot [2\cosh\{-\beta(zJm_B-h)\}]^{N/2}$\
where $<\sigma_i^A>=m_A,~<\sigma_j^B>=m_B, ~\beta = 1/(k_BT),$$ $z$: the number of nearest neighbors at a site.

I expanded the free energy $F=-\frac{1}{\beta}\log Z_{MF}$ in powers of $m_A$ and $m_B$ near the Neel temperature, and introduced the order parameter $n=(m_A - m_B)/2$ and net magnetization $m=(m_A+m_B)/2$. However, the result shows that $$F\propto (...)n^2 + (...)n^4 -\{\frac{1}{8}zJN + \frac{N}{8\beta}(\frac{Jz}{k_BT})^2\}m^2 + (...)m h+ ...,$$ which is not stable about $m$.\

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Approximations above is baed on the so called "Weiss approximation".  In the case of "Bragg-Williams approximation", in which all spin valuables are replaced into the equilibrium value, the above problem is solved...